# ¿Como redireccionar a la misma pagina despues de borrar un registro?

Tags: php

Saludos, estoy intentando redireccionar a la misma pagina luego de haber eliminado un registro, la pagina que me muestra la tabla con los datos de los cuales escojo para eliminar esta en esta dirección:

/SA/admin/info_student.php?ver_curso_eli=&id_alumno=1

Lo que quiero es que al presionar el botón de algún registro, luego de que este sea borrado me redireccione a la pagina con ese id_alumno=1 para seguir viendo los datos de ese estudiante. Dejare la función que borra el registro:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM inscritos WHERE id = '$id'";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);

if($sql>0):
header('Location: AQUI ES DONDE DEBERÍA COLOCAR EL ID DE ESE ALUMNO');
else:
echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
endif;
```

Aclaro que el id que recibo con GET en la función de borrar no es el id del alumno, es el id del registro que estoy eliminando. Muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar con esta duda.

Comment: ¿`location.reload();` es lo que buscas?

Comment: Ese método de JS no lo he utilizado. Como podría aplicarlo en el Francisco y gracias por responder

Comment: Puedes utilizar `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.reload()</script>"`

Comment: Francisco funciona, pero cuando redirecciona se queda como en un bucle infinito recargando la pagina sin parar.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres regresar a la pagina anterior, segun tus comentarios eso creo que es lo que querias:

```
 //opcion 1
   window.history.back()
//opcion 2
   location.href = document.referrer
//O con php
   $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
   header("LOCATION:$url");
```

Answer (score 0):

tu quieres que al borrar el id del alumno se vuelva a redireccionar al mismo archivo para volver a ver todos los datos(suponiendo que sea así, no se si te funcione de esta manera)

```
 header('Location: /SA/admin/info_student.php?ver_curso_eli=&id_alumno');
```

Comment: Pero con eso no me redirecciona a la pagina con el id anterior Daniel, porque estoy borrando es una inscripcion de un estudiante. Lo que quiero es que al borrarla me vuelva a la pagina anterior con los datos del alumno.

Comment: haber si te entendí, esta es la pagina donde están los datos de un alumno(/SA/admin/info_student.php?ver_curso_eli=&id_alumno=1) y al seleccionarlo solo borras algún registro pero quieres volver a ver los mismos datos del alumno y así no te funcionara, es medio confuso tu pregunta header:( /SA/admin/info_student.php?ver_curso_eli=&id_alumno=$id)

Comment: a ver, explico mejor. Esto es la pagina en donde muestro los cursos que le voy a eliminar al alumno: (/SA/admin/info_student.php?ver_curso_eli=&id_alumno=1‌​).  En esa pagina muestro los cursos en los que esta el alumno en una tabla y tengo un botón borrar, lo presiono y le elimina la inscripción a ese alumno, entonces cuando se borrar el registro quiero devolverme a esta misma pagina: (/SA/admin/info_student.php?ver_curso_eli=&id_alumno=1‌​)

Comment: pues si como te decia deber ser asi header('Location: /SA/admin/info_student.php?ver_curso_eli=&id_alumno=1‌'); pero creo que no va dentro de tu archivo que nos estas mostrando, hay alguna manera de poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: en caso de que sea php seria mas o menos asi                                  
     <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit();"> Eliminar</button>
 <a href="SA/admin/info_student.php?ver_curso_eli=&id_alumno=1‌​" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que tienes una página que muestra los datos y las inscripciones del alumno a la que llegas con la URL `/SA/admin/info_student.php?ver_curso_eli=&id_alumno=1`

Luego en esa página tienes un listado de inscripciones del alumno e imagino que cada elemento de la lista contiene un enlace para borrar esa inscripción, ese enlace contiene el ID de la inscripción que quieres borrar.

Al pulsar sobre el enlace se ejecuta el script que toma el ID de la inscripción y lanza la sentencia `DELETE ...`

En este escenario te propongo dos opciones:

1. Pasar también el ID del alumno en la URL que lleva al script de borrado, para que después de borrar puedas volver a la página del alumno usando de nuevo la URL `/SA/admin/info_student.php?ver_curso_eli=&id_alumno=1`
2. Antes de hacer el borrado consultas a la base de datos el ID del alumno al que pertenece la inscripción que estás borrando. Guardas la ID en una variable y tras ejecutar la sentencia de borrado haces el redirect con la ID obtenida como en el caso 1. Esta solución implica una consulta adicional a la base de datos pero es más universal porque te permite borrar una inscripción desde cualquier sitio, por ejemplo desde una vista del curso, una lista de últimas inscripciones realizadas, etc.